# Image drawn in html canvas is not full-sized

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When trying to draw image on canvas using context.drawImage() function , instead of the full image showing on canvas ( both are same size) , it shows only a zoomed area of the image. But when i attach the image to DOM , it shows correctly. You can see the difference in the jsfiddle. The top image is the canvas, the bottom one is the image directly appended to the document body.

https://jsfiddle.net/3fnq62nx/

Also here is the code snippet  , what might be wrong here?

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" style="border: 1px solid black">
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas");
var image = new Image();
image.src = "room_default.jpg";
image.height = "400";
image.width = "800";
image.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: instead of `image.height = "400";
image.width = "800";` write `image.style.height = "400px";
image.style.width = "800px";`

Comment: @RolandStarke I tried that , but it sets canvas size to the image's original dimensions 1174x681.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/3fnq62nx/1/) is your solution

```
var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas");
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://cdn.home-designing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/livingroom_i_by_dragon2525-d3ioeyf.jpg";
image.height = "400";
image.width = "800";
image.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height);
}
```

update `ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height);`

You can pass height and width of event of canvas image as 4th and 5th argument of drawImage function

Comment: That works! But i still dont get why I need to pass those when the resized image and canvas are of the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    hi please check this your issue resolvevar canvas  = document.getElementById("canvas");
var image = new Image();
image.src = "http://cdn.home-designing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/livingroom_i_by_dragon2525-d3ioeyf.jpg";
image.height = "400";
image.width = "800";
image.onload = function(){
    canvas.width = image.width;
    canvas.height = image.height;
    document.body.appendChild(image);
    var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,image.width,image.height);
}
```